# Correct way of creating salted hash password

Tags: php, security, hash, salt, saltedhash

I am new to storing passwords on databases and from what I read I have created a simple php script below

```
<?php
  $salt =  openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (16);
  $password = "test";
  $hash = hash ("sha512" , $salt . $password);

  echo $hash;
?>
```

1. Am I doing this correctly?
2. Should the salt be stored in databases as byte datatype?
3. Should the final hash be stored at String datatype in database?

Comment: What Will happen if any one hacks the db ? they can easily decrypt the password with the salt

Comment: `sha512` cannot be undone. It is a one-way transformation @Vijayaragavendran the only way around it would be to generate a rainbow table for all strings starting with the `$salt`, which is why I prefer to suffix the `$salt` instead of prefixing it.

Comment: it can be stored in a config file with some peculiar file name (Hard to guess)

Comment: you can use the built in PHP function crypt - http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHA* algorithms are not appropriate to hash passwords, because they are ways too fast, and therefore can be brute-forced too fast. Instead one should use a slow algorithm like BCrypt or PBKDF2 with a cost factor, which controls the necessary time.

PHP supports the BCrypt algorithm with the new function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). There also exists a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

It is recommended that you do **not** pass your own salt, instead let the function create a cryptographically safe salt from the random source of the operating system.

The salt will be included in the resulting hash-value, so you don't have to store it separately. Just create a 60 character string field in your database and store the hash-value. The function `password_verify()` will extract the used salt from the stored hash-value. For more information you can have a look at my tutorial about [storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you are running `(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)` then you can take advantage of the built-in php password hashing functionality.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Simple usage:

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM), // or your own salt here
];

$pass_hash = password_hash("helloworld", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

if (password_verify('helloworld', $pass_hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

normally I stored the salt with hashed password. I have my own format to recognize the salt form the hashed password. for example, the hashed password is 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824, and the salt is aaabbb. I append salt to hashed password like 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824aaabbb. So I can recognize the last 6 word is salt for this hashed password. Even the db has been hacked, they still didn't know the salt and the real password.

Comment: what if i tell you, if your db is hijacked in 90% percent your php code is leaked too

Comment: Risk: SQL Injection + ` INTO OUTFILE` -> Filesystem compromise. (Unless your DB is on separate hardware than the webserver.) This is not a good design.