# What about password_hash() in PHP

Tags: php, hash, password-protection

I've been reading all kind of forums and tutorials about this `password_hash()` that seems to be good for password protection.

But now i want to know if it's better to make an own salt and hash for the function like

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Or just let the function do it:

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

There seems to be a lot of discussion about whether or not it's good or bad to use your own salt.

Can somebody explain why its bad (or not) to use your own salt?

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), "Caution - It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one." There are many comments in the docs about how cryptographically safe the auto-generated salt is and that creating your own could result in problems. *It is much more secure* to allow the function to create the salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you don't create your own salt, It will create a secure salt automatically for you.

From the documentation :

> **Caution**
>
> It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for
>   this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if
>   you do not specify one.

So, for answer your question, if you don't know more about salt or other... Just don't use your own salt, this function is strong enough !

Comment: Thanks very much. I also read about that, but wanted to be 100% sure before using it in a website i'm making. I'll mark your answer as correct when i can.

Answer (score 1):

Salts are just a protection against a rainbow table attack.
It won't make one hash more difficult to break but instead the larger whole.
If you use a different salt for every hash, the attacker will need to make a rainbow table for every password.
Which is unpractical in means of work and time.
Generating a salt with a pseudorandom-rng will do the job of protecting the larger whole of your passwords.
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/can-you-help-me-understand-what-a-cryptographic-salt-is

**As the function already generates a secure salt it is not recommended to generate your own with a rng that is practically worse.

Just let the function generate a strong salt and it will be fine and cost less work too as you do not have to create salts yourself.**
[Correct way of creating salted hash password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862499/correct-way-of-creating-salted-hash-password)

Quote from previous link:

> It is recommended that you do not pass your own salt, instead let the function create a cryptographically safe salt from the random source of the operating system.
>
> The salt will be included in the resulting hash-value, so you don't have to store it separately. Just create a 60 character string field in your database and store the hash-value. The function password_verify() will extract the used salt from the stored hash-value. For more information you can have a look at my tutorial about storing passwords.